# Dynamic Chart using Checkboxes and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Found this piece of code online for making a dynamic chart for a dashboard. I want to use checkboxes to add/subtract columns of data from a chart.

The code comes from here: https://peltiertech.com/interactive-charts-with-checkboxes-and-vba/

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("TrueFalseRange").Cells
        rCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not rCell.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

This code works but only when everything is on the same sheet. I want to put the checkbox on another sheet (the dashboard).

Comment: You'll need this `Click` handler in the code-behind of your dashboard sheet.

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify what the problem is, specifically? Questions ideally include a... question.

Comment: Figured it out changed it from active sheet to another sheet. thanks